# Loggin to instagram to scrape user infos

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

I need to scrape infos from an instagram user page, more, I need to use this url page :     `"https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?__a=1"`

The problem is that I need to be loggin with my instagram account to execute this script

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import requests


url_user = "https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?__a=1"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/79.0.309.43'}

response = get(url_user, headers=headers)
print(response)

# print(page.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# print(soup)
jsondata=json.loads(str(soup))
```

I get this error :

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

How can I avoid that connection problem to scrape infos and access data?

Thank you

Comment: Its better to use selenium for this purpose. I don't think this can be achieved using requests. Another way might be to use the instagram API if it is available.

Comment: I already had results while looping thru several users but know Instagram seems to block it. I tried to change my ip address but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `__a=1` parameter gets you a JSON response therefore you do not need to go through BeautifulSoup you simply load the JSON directly.

```
response = get(url_user, headers=headers)
jsondata=json.loads(response.text)
```

Alternatively you can use the [`json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) function to load the JSON:

```
response = get(url_user, headers=headers)
jsondata = response.json()
```